# php header function not working for me

Tags: php

This is my code everything working fine and data is also inserting in database but after function execution i don't get a redirect.
Here is a definition of function and at the end calling of function

```
require_once('config.php');

function addRecord($post = array(),$table,$ommit) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = $sql2 = "";
    $ommitFields = explode(',',$ommit);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' SET';
    foreach($post as $key=>$val){
        if(!in_array($key,$ommitFields) and $val !='') {
            $sql2 .= ", $key='$val'";
        }
    }
    $sql2 = trim($sql2, ',');
    $sql = $sql.$sql2;
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}

if($_POST['axn'] == 'insert') {
    if(addRecord($_POST,'data_table','axn') == TRUE) {
        header('location:index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: You nothing return from function, so if can't work

Comment: please i am new one in php kindly let me know that what should in change in this code

Comment: i have tried this one if(addRecord($_POST,'data_table','axn')){header('location:index.php');} but still not working for me

Comment: If you want something to equal TRUE, then you need to return TRUE.

Comment: You also have a serious sql injection problem, on both the keys (use a white-list) and the values (use a prepared statement or escape the values).

Answer (score 1):

because your function does not return code, if works wrong.  write in the end of function :

```
return mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want:

```
function addRecord($post = array(),$table,$ommit) {
    global $conn;
    $sql = $sql2 = "";
    $ommitFields = explode(',',$ommit);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.mysql_real_escape_string($table).' SET';
    foreach($post as $key=>$val){
        if(!in_array($key,$ommitFields) and $val !='') {
            $sql2 .= ", $key='$val'";
        }
    }
    $sql2 = trim($sql2, ',');
    $sql = $sql.$sql2;
    return mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
```

This returns the result of [mysqli_query](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), TRUE or FALSE depending on the success of the database query.

Comment: Thank you so much its working fine may you live long and always be happy May God bless you

Comment: @Naqqashrana Remember to accept an answer when your question is resolved.